# ASP.NET Kentico redirect folder to default to index.htm file

Tags: asp.net, iis, kentico

I have a Kentico 8.1 site.

I need to be able to add html files using ftp.  there file are stored example:

/specialoffer/index.html

I want to be able to use http://www.domain.com/specialoffer and have it default to

http://www.domain.com/specialoffer/index.html.

Currently this is NOT working.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

in this case this HTML page should not be processed by Kentico, so you should add "/specialoffer" folder to excluded URLs (check the [Documentation of settings](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Settings+-+URLs+and+SEO)) and then achieve your goal via URL Rewrite.

Comment: What if I have ens of URLs I need to exclude.  Is there a better way to do this?  I can turn of "page not found" setting in Kentico and do it all through IIS if its better